# using lp_solve in java with mac, no lpsolve55j in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, lpsolve

I have included the `lpsolve55j.jar` in Eclipse, but it still gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lpsolve55j in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1764)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1044)
    at lpsolve.LpSolve.<clinit>(LpSolve.java:274)
    at Run.main(Run.java:11)
```

I tried the [instructions here](http://diegoresearch.wordpress.com/2008/07/10/using-lp_solve-in-java-with-mac-os-x/)

```
Miranda-Macbook: sh ccc.osx
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-long-double"
libtool: can't open file: lp_MDO.o (No such file or directory)
libtool: can't open file: commonlib.o (No such file or directory)
libtool: can't open file: mmio.o (No such file or directory)
...
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-long-double"
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: bin/osx64/liblpsolve55.a: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: lp_MDO.o: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: commonlib.o: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: mmio.o: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: myblas.o: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: ini.o: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: fortify.o: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: colamd.o: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: lp_rlp.o: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: lp_crash.o: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: lp_LUSOL.o: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: lusol.o: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: lp_Hash.o: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: lp_lib.o: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: lp_wlp.o: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: lp_matrix.o: No such file or directory
...
Miranda-Macbook: ls liblp*
ls: liblp*: No such file or directory
```

So I downloaded `lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_osx32.tar.gz`, which gives me: `liblpsolve55.a` and `liblpsolve55.dylib` then:

```
sudo cp liblpsolve55.a liblpsolve55.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

Tried demo, it works!

```
Miranda-Macbook: sh ccc
Miranda-Macbook: ./demo
```

but java code in eclipse still not working so keep going, change the `lp_solve_5.5_java/lib/mac/build-osx` file line 14 to:

```
LPSOLVE_DIR=/Users/miranda_zhang/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5
```

then try to build the JNI extension:

```
Miranda-Macbook: sh build-osx
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/liblpsolve55.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_put_bb_nodefunc", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_registerBbNodefunc in lpsolve5j.o
  "_put_bb_branchfunc", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_registerBbBranchfunc in lpsolve5j.o
  "_put_msgfunc", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_registerMsgfunc in lpsolve5j.o
  "_put_logfunc", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_registerLogfunc in lpsolve5j.o
  "_put_abortfunc", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_registerAbortfunc in lpsolve5j.o
  "_print_solution", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_printSolution in lpsolve5j.o
  "_print_objective", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_printObjective in lpsolve5j.o
  "_print_tableau", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_printTableau in lpsolve5j.o
  "_print_scales", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_printScales in lpsolve5j.o
  "_print_duals", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_printDuals in lpsolve5j.o
  "_print_constraints", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_printConstraints in lpsolve5j.o
  "_print_lp", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_printLp in lpsolve5j.o
  "_reset_params", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_resetParams in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_basisvar", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setBasisvar in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_constr_value", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getConstrValue in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_use_names", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setUseNames in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_use_names", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isUseNames in lpsolve5j.o
  "_lp_solve_version", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_lpSolveVersion in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_nameindex", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getNameindex in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_nativeXLI", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isNativeXLI in lpsolve5j.o
  "_has_XLI", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_hasXLI in lpsolve5j.o
  "_has_BFP", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_hasBFP in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_nativeBFP", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isNativeBFP in lpsolve5j.o
  "_unscale", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_unscale in lpsolve5j.o
     (maybe you meant: _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_unscale)
  "_get_basiscrash", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getBasiscrash in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_basiscrash", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setBasiscrash in lpsolve5j.o
  "_default_basis", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_defaultBasis in lpsolve5j.o
  "_reset_basis", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_resetBasis in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_lp_index", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getLpIndex in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_orig_index", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getOrigIndex in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_Lrows", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getLrows in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getLambda in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPtrLambda in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_nonzeros", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getNonzeros in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_Norig_columns", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getNorigColumns in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_Norig_rows", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getNorigRows in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_Ncolumns", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getNcolumns in lpsolve5j.o
      getSensitivityObjex(JNIEnv_*, _jobject*, _jdoubleArray*, _jdoubleArray*, _jdoubleArray*, _jdoubleArray*)in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPtrSensitivityObjex in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPtrSensitivityObj in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getSensitivityObj in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPtrDualSolution in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getDualSolution in lpsolve5j.o
      ...
  "_get_Nrows", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getNrows in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPtrDualSolution in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getDualSolution in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPtrSensitivityRhs in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getSensitivityRhs in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPtrPrimalSolution in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPrimalSolution in lpsolve5j.o
      ...
  "_delete_lp", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_deleteLp in lpsolve5j.o
  "_print_str", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_printStr in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_var_dualresult", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getVarDualresult in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_var_primalresult", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getVarPrimalresult in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_working_objective", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getWorkingObjective in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_objective", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getObjective in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_feasible", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isFeasible in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_statustext", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getStatustext in lpsolve5j.o
      throw_exception_with_status(JNIEnv_*, _lprec*, char const*)in lpsolve5j.o
  "_solve", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_solve in lpsolve5j.o
     (maybe you meant: _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_solve)
  "_get_total_nodes", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getTotalNodes in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_max_level", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getMaxLevel in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_total_iter", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getTotalIter in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_negrange", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getNegrange in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_negrange", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setNegrange in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_simplextype", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getSimplextype in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_simplextype", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setSimplextype in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_preferdual", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setPreferdual in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_piv_rule", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isPivRule in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_piv_mode", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isPivMode in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_pivoting", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPivoting in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_pivoting", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setPivoting in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_improve", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getImprove in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_improve", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setImprove in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_scalelimit", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getScalelimit in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_scalelimit", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setScalelimit in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_integerscaling", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isIntegerscaling in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_scaletype", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isScaletype in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_scalemode", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isScalemode in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_scaling", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getScaling in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_scaling", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setScaling in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_break_at_value", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getBreakAtValue in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_break_at_value", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setBreakAtValue in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_break_at_first", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isBreakAtFirst in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_break_at_first", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setBreakAtFirst in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_var_priority", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getVarPriority in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_var_branch", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getVarBranch in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_bb_floorfirst", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getBbFloorfirst in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_bb_floorfirst", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setBbFloorfirst in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_obj_bound", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getObjBound in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_obj_bound", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setObjBound in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_solutionlimit", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getSolutionlimit in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_solutionlimit", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setSolutionlimit in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_solutioncount", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getSolutioncount in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_bb_depthlimit", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getBbDepthlimit in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_bb_depthlimit", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setBbDepthlimit in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_bb_rule", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getBbRule in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_bb_rule", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setBbRule in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_maxpivot", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getMaxpivot in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_maxpivot", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setMaxpivot in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_presolveloops", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPresolveloops in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_presolve", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPresolve in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_presolve", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isPresolve in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_presolve", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setPresolve in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_anti_degen", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getAntiDegen in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_anti_degen", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isAntiDegen in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_anti_degen", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setAntiDegen in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_add_rowmode", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isAddRowmode in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_add_rowmode", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setAddRowmode in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_lag_trace", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isLagTrace in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_lag_trace", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setLagTrace in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_trace", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isTrace in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_trace", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setTrace in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_debug", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isDebug in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_debug", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setDebug in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_print_sol", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPrintSol in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_print_sol", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setPrintSol in lpsolve5j.o
  "_time_elapsed", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_timeElapsed in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_timeout", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getTimeout in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_timeout", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setTimeout in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_verbose", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getVerbose in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_verbose", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setVerbose in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_rh", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getRh in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_mip_gap", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getMipGap in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_mip_gap", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setMipGap in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_status", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getStatus in lpsolve5j.o
      throw_exception_with_status(JNIEnv_*, _lprec*, char const*)in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_epsperturb", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getEpsperturb in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_epsperturb", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setEpsperturb in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_epspivot", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getEpspivot in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_epspivot", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setEpspivot in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_epsel", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getEpsel in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_epsel", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setEpsel in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_epsd", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getEpsd in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_epsd", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setEpsd in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_epsb", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getEpsb in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_epsb", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setEpsb in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_epsint", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getEpsint in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_epsint", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setEpsint in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_infinite", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isInfinite in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_infinite", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getInfinite in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_infinite", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setInfinite in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_semicont", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isSemicont in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_binary", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isBinary in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_int", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isInt in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_rh_range", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getRhRange in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_bounds_tighter", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getBoundsTighter in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_bounds_tighter", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setBoundsTighter in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_negative", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isNegative in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_unbounded", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isUnbounded in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_upbo", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getUpbo in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_lowbo", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getLowbo in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_maxim", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isMaxim in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_sense", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setSense in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_minim", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setMinim in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_maxim", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setMaxim in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_mat", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getMat in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_SOS_var", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isSOSVar in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_rh_vec", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setRhVec in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_origcol_name", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getOrigcolName in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_col_name", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getColName in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_origrow_name", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getOrigrowName in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_row_name", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getRowName in lpsolve5j.o
  "_column_in_lp", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_columnInLp in lpsolve5j.o
  "_is_constr_type", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_isConstrType in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_lp_name", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getLpName in lpsolve5j.o
  "_read_XLI", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_readXLI in lpsolve5j.o
  "_read_freeMPS", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_readFreeMps in lpsolve5j.o
  "_read_MPS", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_readMps in lpsolve5j.o
  "_read_LP", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_readLp in lpsolve5j.o
  "_copy_lp", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_copyLp in lpsolve5j.o
  "_make_lp", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_makeLp in lpsolve5j.o
  "_print_debugdump", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_printDebugdump in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_outputfile", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setOutputfile in lpsolve5j.o
  "_write_XLI", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_writeXLI in lpsolve5j.o
  "_read_basis", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_readBasis in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_XLI", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setXLI in lpsolve5j.o
  "_write_freemps", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_writeFreeMps in lpsolve5j.o
  "_write_params", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_writeParams in lpsolve5j.o
  "_read_params", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_readParams in lpsolve5j.o
  "_write_basis", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_writeBasis in lpsolve5j.o
  "_write_mps", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_writeMps in lpsolve5j.o
  "_write_lp", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_writeLp in lpsolve5j.o
  "_dualize_lp", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_dualizeLp in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_BFP", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setBFP in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_basis", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getBasis in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_basis", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setBasis in lpsolve5j.o
  "_guess_basis", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_guessBasis in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_lambda", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getLambda in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPtrLambda in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_sensitivity_objex", referenced from:
      getSensitivityObjex(JNIEnv_*, _jobject*, _jdoubleArray*, _jdoubleArray*, _jdoubleArray*, _jdoubleArray*)in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_sensitivity_obj", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPtrSensitivityObj in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getSensitivityObj in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_dual_solution", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPtrDualSolution in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getDualSolution in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_sensitivity_rhs", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPtrSensitivityRhs in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getSensitivityRhs in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_primal_solution", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPtrPrimalSolution in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPrimalSolution in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_constraints", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPtrConstraints in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getConstraints in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_variables", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPtrVariables in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getVariables in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_var_weights", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setVarWeights in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_var_branch", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setVarBranch in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_rh", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setRh in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_epslevel", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setEpslevel in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_semicont", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setSemicont in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_binary", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setBinary in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_int", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setInt in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_rh_range", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setRhRange in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_bounds", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setBounds in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_unbounded", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setUnbounded in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_upbo", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setUpbo in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_lowbo", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setLowbo in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_columnex", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getColumnex in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_column", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPtrColumn in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getColumn in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_rowex", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getRowex in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_row", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getPtrRow in lpsolve5j.o
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getRow in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_mat", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setMat in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_obj", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setObj in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_obj_fnex", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setObjFnex in lpsolve5j.o
  "_str_set_obj_fn", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_strSetObjFn in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_obj_fn", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setObjFn in lpsolve5j.o
  "_add_SOS", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_addSOS in lpsolve5j.o
  "_get_constr_type", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_getConstrType in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_constr_type", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setConstrType in lpsolve5j.o
  "_str_set_rh_vec", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_strSetRhVec in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_col_name", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setColName in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_row_name", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setRowName in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_columnex", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setColumnex in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_column", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setColumn in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_rowex", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setRowex in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_row", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setRow in lpsolve5j.o
  "_del_column", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_delColumn in lpsolve5j.o
  "_str_add_column", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_strAddColumn in lpsolve5j.o
  "_add_columnex", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_addColumnex in lpsolve5j.o
  "_add_column", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_addColumn in lpsolve5j.o
  "_str_add_lag_con", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_strAddLagCon in lpsolve5j.o
  "_add_lag_con", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_addLagCon in lpsolve5j.o
  "_del_constraint", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_delConstraint in lpsolve5j.o
  "_str_add_constraint", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_strAddConstraint in lpsolve5j.o
  "_add_constraintex", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_addConstraintex in lpsolve5j.o
  "_add_constraint", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_addConstraint in lpsolve5j.o
  "_set_lp_name", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_setLpName in lpsolve5j.o
  "_resize_lp", referenced from:
      _Java_lpsolve_LpSolve_resizeLp in lpsolve5j.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Miranda-Macbook: ls
build-osx   lpsolve5j.o
Miranda-Macbook: ls liblpsolve55j.jnilib
ls: liblpsolve55j.jnilib: No such file or directory
```

Stuck again

---

Since I couldn't install it on my old mac, I used my other windows computer.